# Using Robolectric for testing Android application

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric

Actually, I have two questions about Robolectric.

A small introduction:

My application consists of three classes. An application (class MyApp), an activity (class MainActivity) and a class (class InAppConfig) with some settings (all of them are saved as static fields) that I initialize in Application.onCreate  method. Now about testing part. Lets think about it as just a single test class that has several test methods.

The first problem is that RobolectricTestRunner creates a new instance of MyApp class for each test method (that causes multiple initialization of InAppConfig). That is not acceptable in my case and I am looking for any solution that doesn't involve changing the code of an application under the test.

The second problem is that every time I am trying to start an activity in a test I get an Exception (Resources$NotFoundException). I am doing it like this:

```
private final ActivityController<MainActivity> controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
...
final MainActivity activity = controller.create().start().resume().get();
```

I have found some sort of solution in this case: test works if I comment applicationId in my build.grdale file. (build.gradle looks like this:)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 20
        versionName '0.9.8.2'

        // applicationId 'my.package.org'
    }
 ...
}
```

But, of course, I want to keep applicationId in my build file, so it is still a problem.
Also, it looks like there is an open issue posted on Robolectrics git repo which is related to the same problem. ( https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/110 )

If you have any ideas how those problems can be solved, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

A stacktrace is enclosed below for the second issue:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: no such label my.package.org:string/title_activity_main
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.getActivityTitle(ActivityController.java:97)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:44)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:114)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.onepf.sample.trivialdrive.ActivityInitTest.test1(ActivityInitTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please put in the stacktrace for the exception you are getting, otherwise we can't help. 
Also, you get best answers when SO when you ask each question separately, makes it easier to answer and discuss each one by itself.

Comment: @AlexFlorescu, I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: Roboletric is for unit testing. Inits application before each test case is good approach, because it give you isolation and independent state between tests. If you want to go with unit testing, you have to test small pieces of code. If you want test more (functional), look at Android Instrumentation.

Comment: Using something like Robolectric generally implies a different app architecture to help make testing easier; using something like dependency injection with Roboguice and/or specifying a different Application class in a test manifest will let you avoid startup configuration issues, but not without changing application code.